# How to reshape a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, melt

[image]

This is my dataFrame and I want it to look like this:

[image]

I think I should use pd.melt() but I am not very sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if it helps:

```
df =pd.pivot_table(df, index=["Cabin_letter"], columns=["Survived"], values=["No. Passengers"])
df.columns = ["dead", "Survived"]
df.reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution I searched for.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you are looking for?

```
df.groupby(['Cabin_letter'],as_index=False).sum().reset_index()
df['died'] = df['Survived'] - df['No.passangers']
```